# Get pivot from two model instance

Tags: laravel-5

I have a question. `Activity` model and `User` model have many-to-many relationships. I know I can get pivot model like this:

```
$activities = $user->activities;
foreach($activities as $activity)
{
    $pivot = $activity->pivot;
}
```

But now I already have two model instance:`$user` and `$activity` .Get them by id individually. Not access from their relationship. So I want to know is there a method to get their pivot model?

Answer (score 0):

Its not necessary for you to call the relationship chain to access pivot, you can query individual model and access pivot too,

```
$model = Activity::find(1);  //get the activity model by primary key
$model->pivot->activityId;
```